# How do I remove special characters from a file?

Tags: sed, special-characters, delete

I have a file that contains :

```
<class>
these are special @ $ characters / < > & " '
</class>
```

I want to remove all the special characters only, between `<class>  </class>`.

I tried this command.

```
sed  "s/[^a-zA-Z0-9(<.class>)(<\/class>)/ /g" file.txt
```

In above command I have tried to keep alphabets, numeral, tags and everything else should be removed.

But it's not giving me the output I want.

Comment: What is the input and what is the expected output. Also, is that the literal `sed` command that you tried? It is missing a `]` somewhere.

Comment: This seems like it might be an XY problem. What is the problem that you are trying to solve with this? There might be a better solution than `sed`, but I would need to know what your file currently looks like (is it just what you show here?) and what the file should look like. If you're trying to modify an HTML or XML file, `sed` isn't always the best tool for the job because it can produce a malformed document.

Comment: Please look at [How to do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is only one block of `class` and each tag is in a separate line, this will work for you in GNU awk:

```
awk '/<\/class>/{p=0};p{gsub(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/," ")};/<class>/{p=1};1' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Done by below `sed` command tested and worked fine Using below command i removed all special characters `[<>&$@/'"]` between `<class> and </class>`

input.txt

```
<class>
these are special @ $ characters / < > & " '
</class>
```

command

```
sed -n '/<class>/,/<\/class>/p' input.txt | sed '/^[a-z]/s/[<>&$@/]//g' | sed "s/'//g" | sed 's/"//g'
```

output

```
<class>
these are special   characters
</class>
```

Comment: that works as long as the `<class>` tags are on lines of their own

Comment: This remove lines before <class> or after </class>.